# Android Proguard Release causes not executing for-loop

Tags: android, for-loop, proguard

In my Android app I am building in release mode. With Proguard activated an rare issue is caused, a specific for-loop never is executed:

```
List<MyClass> objectList = getObjectList();
Log.d("Step 1", String.valueOf(objectList.size())); //Print size > 0

for(MyClass object: objectList) {
  Log.d("Step 2", object.toString()); //Never printed
  ...
}
```

The "Step 1" Log is printed correctly and `objectList.size() > 0`. I don't understand what is causing "Step 2" Log is never printed (and all code into for-loop never executed). I am using the Android Device manager Logcat.

In debug mode or with Proguard disabled this snippet works correctly.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I just added `-dontoptimize` but the problem was not resolved. This is my proguard-rules file:

```
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-keepnames class com.androidplot.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.acra.** { *; }
-keep,allowoptimization class com.mypackage.myapp.model.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-dontwarn com.mypackage.myapp.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Comment: possibly your `toString` returns null or an empty string, in which case it is not logged

Comment: Not, those cases are validated, moreover `toString()` is `@Override` in MyClass and always prints a String.

Comment: did you try to log something else, to make sure this is not happening?

Comment: Yes, moreover the for-loop contains more code, not only the Log.d instruction.

Comment: next step would be to decompile the obfuscated code to see exactly what is executed as a result of the proguard run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html

> Disappearing loops
>
> If your code contains empty busy-waiting loops,
> ProGuard's optimization step may remove them. More specifically, this
> happens if a loop continuously checks the value of a non-volatile
> field that is changed in a different thread. The specifications of the
> Java Virtual Machine require that you always mark fields that are
> accessed across different threads without further synchronization as
> volatile. If this is not possible for some reason, you'll have to
> switch off optimization using the -dontoptimize option.

Comment: Thanks @Terence, I added `-dontoptimize` to proguard rules file, but the problem persist. I just update the question with proguard rules file content.

Comment: I don't know that proguard is able to tell that `Log.d` doesn't do anything useful. It does write to a stream that goes out of the app, so I don't think proguard would be entitled to consider it useless.

Comment: Are you using Jackson or Gson in your code? Your classes specific to Json data will have to be prevented from obsfucation.

Comment: I am using `-keepattributes *Annotation*` and `-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }` in the proguard rules file. Is it enough for prevent obfuscation in Jackson classes?. The problem still remains, I had to release without proguard... It is a nightmare!!!

Comment: Yes @squeeish, I rewrote the code. I never found the error cause.